# Kivy remote shell. Getting APK 'parse error' on Android device

Tags: android, python, apk, kivy

I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy-remote-shell) for building the kivy-remote-shell apk and it builds without errors. However, when I try to install the APK on my device, I get an error message,

> Parse Error: There was a problem parsing the package

I don't know what to do about that, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that:

- the APK is signed, at least with your own certificate.
- you apply "zipalign" to the package. "zipalign" is a tool which is part of the SDK. The command line is something like: `zipalign 4 infile.apk outfile.apk`, see also http://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html